# AWS EC2 RDS cannot connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL server running in RDS. I am able to connect to it when I'm running my website on localhost. But when I try to connect to myself through my website being hosted by the EC2 instance I can't connect. I tried looking through the security groups in the EC2 and it has as in inbound rule the following:

MYSQL/Aurora.  TCP.  3306.  0.0.0.0/0

I'm sure the password, username, host, and database are correct because I can connect with them on localhost and through MySQL workbench.

I try to connect to mysql as follows:

```
$mysqli= mysqli_connect("blah.foo.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",'root','password', "innodb")or die($mysqli->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should connect it like

```
mysqli_connect("blah.foo.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",'root','password',
"innodb",'3306')or die($mysqli->error);
```

Connection string look like [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference. Also how would that account for me being able to access MySQL in via localhost and not on the EC2 server ? That's the weird part to me.